# function in my app.js that i cannot call inline in my page

Tags: javascript, ejs

```
import './vendors/jquery';
import './vendors/jquery.tagsinput'; // <--- here i call my tags.input lib
import './carousel';
import './featherlight';
import './top-nav';
etc...
```

this is the app.js file where i import my libs and my js
and here under is where i call my app.js file, then i use a specific script into my ejs file that loop on some ejs variables. But addTag function that come from tagsinput librairie seems to be undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
<% if(creations.Tags) { %>
    <% for(var i=0; i < creations.Tags.length; i++) { %>
        <a><%= creations.Tags[i].TagSpotting.name %> %></a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(document).ready(function() {
            j("#tags").addTag(ejs.render('<%=creations.Tags[i].TagSpotting.name %>'));
        })
       </script>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to pass a variable in the js file and alert it in my ejs. The variable was not defined. I passed it to window as a global variable and it worked fined. But i just cannot change the way the plug-in is builded. So i tried to import it in a script tag like a simple plugin. In my express file app use public folder (where webpack compile all js as app.js) and assetics (where all files are written one by one) so in the ejs i added a script tag which linked to the plugin that remain in the assetics folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/vendors/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
```

Now it work as i wanted but i don't understand why when the plugin is compiled in public folder as app.js its not running normally and why i have to call it twice like this.